# Flex3: where to find loading animations? Is it possible to load GIF images easily?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, loading, gif

I would like to use a GIF image as a loading animation on my Flex application, however I read Flex 3 doesn't have native support for GIF images. Therefore, is there any way to use them without any drawbacks?
If not, where can I find some flash animations to include in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of progress indicator flash animations out there as swf which can be easily be embedded (ie. [here](http://preloaderz.com/design/free-preloader-animations/)) or search google for Flex Progress Spinner. It's not that difficult to implement your own anyway. You just need a canvas and some matematics (rotation about point formulars).

Comment: another sample could be this: http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1219018. Please feel free to accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. You can find and design your own loading animation in:
http://www.ajaxload.info/. All you need to do is add this image in canvas or anyobject then call this one everytime you load.hope this will help you